# sqlalchemy : querying an existing table in the database

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I understand how to create a table and query it using sqlalchemy. But what I am trying to do is different. I just want to query a table that already exists and which I did not create. What that means is I won't have a Python class defined for it in my code.

How do I query such a table ?

Comment: Defining a class for a table in Python is a declaration that such a table exists in the database. It does not necessitate creating the table via SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an existing table using the following code.
For example if your table is users then:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
Users = Base.classes.users
session = Session(engine)
res = session.query(Users).first()
```